# Permission denied on virtualbox jupyter notebook

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, jupyter, 777

I have set up an Ubuntu virtualbox on my Win 10 laptop, but am having difficulty using magic to use a file. So far all I have is

```
%install_ext https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SchlossLab/ipython-mothurmagic/master/mothurmagic.py

%load_ext mothurmagic

%%mothur
set.dir(help)
```

the last few lines are just to check that everything's working, but I get back permission denied. I have tried giving 755 permissions to everything in the path since I have read a lot about directory permissions etc. and have now reached the point where I have run

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /home
```

and still I get permission denied. I have tried running jupyter notebook with %%mothur and it works on a mac os x el capitan computer, not sure what else I can do at this point. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! I am a super noob, but am trying to dip my toes in, coming out empty handed.